# when to choose predictive power of a model over explainability?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, predictive-models, boosting

I am currently working on a binary classification with 1000 records. class distribution is 75:25

I tried both logistic and random forests, My results are better for random forests.

However, when I try Xgboost, they are even better than random forests.

Meaning, the recall for minority class increases by 3 points (from 39 to 42).

And our business objective is to identify/predict the negatives correctly (missing negatives is costly and critical for the business).

My questions are as follows

a) As a data scientist, considering the dataset size, I am not naturally inclined to try Xgboost because I feel it is overkill for such a small dataset. note, I already tried hyperparamter tuning for RF. I could only get 39% recall for minority. So, should I go for Xgboost for the sake of predictive power?

With the advent of Explainable AI solutions like Lime, Shap etc, do you think it is okay to go for high end models like boosting even for small dataset if predictive power is important?

Comment: I think this is opinion-based, or at least the reasoning for choosing your approach is entirely up to you. In a perfect world, all models would be easily interpreted, but that's not reality. So either interpretability is the top priority, and you use a model that you can interpret, or precision of the model is the top priority, and you use the best model. If Lime/Shap/etc solves the interpretation problem, so much the better, but the sequence of questions you've asked about how to understand Lime/etc suggests that they're challenging tools to use.

Comment: There exists a Pareto front of choices of models under these criterion. Try to aim for a Pareto-efficient choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on exactly what kind of interpretability you need.

I understand your feeling that XGBoost is overkill. However, it *is* the best thing you found, right? So, might as well use it? Unless it's causing issues because of computation constraints, I'd go ahead with XGBoost (if you're confident there's no overfitting going on).

So, what kind of interpretability do you need? If you need some kind of broad measure of feature importance, then you can certainly get that with these complex methods! The only thing you can't really get with something like XGBoost (that you could easily get with logistic regression) is a super direct feature coefficient representing "If you increase this variable by 1, the prediction will go up/down by X". LIME and Permutation Feature Importance are great tools that, I think, will take care of your interpretability needs in most cases.

Comment: That last sentence doesn't even apply in all *linear* models! If you have an $x_1x_2$ interaction term, then how much $y$ changes when you increase $x_1$ depends on the value of $x_2$.

Comment: @Dave You're right, but I just mean that it's pretty straightforward to extract that information from linear regression or logistic regression, interaction terms or not.

Comment: Thanls for your help.